# Some questions regarding building a SSD (into my Fractal Design Define R5 Case)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I am looking to upgrade my build with a 500GB Samsung 850 EVO SSD. I have never built in a hard drive, and I'm generally not really familiar with adding components to my computer. I know the routines, but I usually prefer to work on the internals and leave the component work to experts. However, I think I can handle to add a hard drive, so:

My case is the [Fractal design define R5](http://www.fractal-design.com/home/product/cases/define-series/define-r5-black). My questions are:

1) What kind of cables/ridges etc. would I have to buy with my ssd? Is there a quality difference, especially in cables?

My guess would be a 6gb/s sata cable, but I am not sure about the ridge, and because I barely every touch my build, I am not really an expert to judge this. I know my case has 2 ssd slots, but I don't know if extra ridges or holders are required.

And I have two other questions which are not directly related to my case:

2) Is a clean, fresh OS install preferable to a migration? I am not sure about it considering there could be some referencing problems internally, by not updating to the new file paths etc.

3) Is one big SSD favoured, or am I better off buying 2 smaller ones? The prices would be identical for both, however, depending on the result for question 1), another set of ridge/cable would come in. I am using the AsRock Z97 Fatality, so there would be enough space for more than one ssd
Thanks in advance for taking your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by ridges you mean mounts.

Any SATA cable will do that is long enough, all SATA cables are the same.

You case will have mounting slots but you need screws to mount the SSD, these wont usually come with the SSD but come with the case and motherboard. If somebody else built it for you you may need to purchase screws.

You can clone the current disk, its not a problem once you use a cloning tool as its an EXACT copy of the existing install. If you want to do this, buy a kit SSD, not just the SSD itself.

Buy one big one, two smaller ones are useful for RAIDs, but thats for advanced users and not really applicable except in very specialized situations.

Comment: What special things does the kit offer? I see a connection cable to USB, but wouldn't moving data be possible without that as well? As far as I know the basic SSDs also contain the disk with the Samsung Migration Software. I might as well be very wrong here. But thanks so far! Screws are there and I'm not looking for a RAID setup :)

Comment: You need the USB adapter kit if your cloning tool is a program, if its bootable image you can get away without the USB.